# Looking for an API endpoint to get list of available github actions in the market place

Tags: api, github, github-actions

I am looking for an API endpoint to get the list of available actions and their detail in the GitHub action marketplace.

Is there any possibility other than web scraping?

Comment: After looking for an official endpoint, I only found those for the Github Marketplace: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/apps#marketplace (from https://docs.github.com/en/developers/github-marketplace) Unfortunately, there isn't any endpoint to list available actions yet. The only option seems to be with the web site https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd I tried it. but unfortunately in the marketplace page its only possible to proceed for 25 pages. and it means only 1000 actions. I tried. also with category filtering and reached around 5000 actions (again only 25 pages for each category) but apparently there are more than 8000 actions. I don't know how to get all ...